# MySQL Workplace Query

Tags: mysql

I have the following employee table:

- Employee(Columns: Emp_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, DOB)
- Department(Columns: Dept_Name, Dept_ID)
- Dept_Emp(Columns: Emp_ID, Dept_ID)

Say I am given the employee ID of 1 and I want to find all of the employees who work in the same department as the employee with ID 1 and return their name from the Employee table. I am having trouble formulating the query for such a task.

I was thinking it would look start to look something like:

```
SELECT Dept_Emp.Emp_ID
FROM Dept_Emp d1, Dept_Emp d2
WHERE d1.Emp_ID = '1'
AND d1.Dept_ID = d2.Dept_ID;
```

On the inside of some nested query? But I am not sure, as queries get more complex I get more confused and I tend to overthink. Thank you for your time.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Usually, an employee only works in one department at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution would be using subquery.

```
SELECT Emp_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, DOB
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Dept_Emp ON Employee.Emp_ID = Dept_Emp.Emp_ID 
WHERE Dept_Emp.Dept_ID = (SELECT D1.Dept_ID FROM Dept_Emp D1 WHERE D1.Emp_Id = 1 )
```

**Note**: If an employee belongs to multiple departments use `IN` operator.

```
SELECT Emp_ID, First_Name, Last_Name, DOB
FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Dept_Emp ON Employee.Emp_ID = Dept_Emp.Emp_ID 
WHERE Dept_Emp.Dept_ID IN (SELECT D1.Dept_ID FROM Dept_Emp D1 WHERE D1.Emp_Id = 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple query for output:

```
SELECT a.Emp_ID, a.First_Name, a.Last_Name, a.DOB, b.Dept_ID FROM Dept_Emp as b LEFT JOIN Employee as a ON a.Emp_ID = b.Emp_ID WHERE b.Dept_ID=(SELECT Dept_ID FROM Dept_Emp WHERE Emp_ID = 1 LIMIT 1)
```